# How to verify objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I am trying to make and store usernames and passwords in cleartext.  I am not doing any type of authentication (I know I could be using node passport to do this, and encrypting, but I am just learning javascript, so I am just trying to play around)

I have an object that I have globally defined like this:

```
var obj= {username: req.body.username,
          password: req.body.password}
```

that I am pushing onto my registeredUsers array:

```
var registeredUsers = new Array();
```

My issue is that I want to be able to do something like:

```
   if((($.inArray(username, registerdUsers) == username && 
($.inArray(password, registerdUsers)) == password){     
    res.redirect("/?error=Already Registered"); 
    }
```

This doesn't work, how can I check both values of my object to see if they are contained in my array?

Here are the functions that I am doing the authentication in case anyone is curious:

```
function ensureAuthentication(req, res, next){
    //push object onto the registeredUsers array
    registeredUsers.push(obj);
    //if the user is already registered, throw error
    if (($.inArray(username, registeredUsers) && ($.inArray(password, registeredUsers)) {//obj.contains() username){
        res.redirect("/?error=Already Registered"); 
    }
    //if new user
    else{
        authentication.push(obj);
        console.log("added new user);
        //redirect to homepage
        res.rediret("/");
    }
}
```

and

```
function login(req, res) {
    //var username = req.body.username;
    req.session.username = username;
    req.session.password = password;
    loggedInUsers[username] = LoggedIn;
    if((($.inArray(username, registerdUsers) == username && ($.inArray(password, registerdUsers)) == password){
        //increase login count
        for(users in loggedInUsers){
            ++loginCount;
            console.log("Login Count: ", loginCount);
        }
        //redirect to login page
        res.redirect("/users")
    }
    else{
        //print out error message
        res.redirect("/?error=Error: incorrect username/password");
    }
}
```

Comment: `inArray` returns a number, what's this supposed to do `$.inArray(username, registerdUsers) == username`

Comment: What is this `$` thing?

Comment: @minitech, i suspect lodash or underscore

Comment: I want to see if the password entered is the correct password for the username

Comment: in thefunction `login`, specifically `req.session.username = username;` where is username and password defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the object by username:

```
var user;

for(var i = 0; user = registeredUsers[i]; i++) {
    if(user.username === username)
        break;
}
```

Check the password:

```
var valid = user && user.password === password;
```

Answer (score 1):

$.inArray is like Java's indexOf function which returns the index of the position if the obj is in the array, otherwise -1

So something like..

```
if((($.inArray(username, registerdUsers) !== -1 && 
($.inArray(password, registerdUsers)) !== -1){     
    res.redirect("/?error=Already Registered"); 
}
```

..would check to make sure you don't have any duplicate users with the exact same password, but allow duplicate users.

I think you are looking for something like..

```
if($.inArray(username, registeredUsers) !== -1){     
    res.redirect("/?error=Already Registered"); 
}
```

which says, if the username exists in the registeredUsers array, then give the error msg 'Already Registered'

Comment: I should have stated that I was using server side javascript, not client side, so I can't use the $ notation... but it definitely did help me understand better, thank you!